# Can we use same aggregate function more than once on same table field or column using Different filter conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I want to use **SUM()** function on 'Amount' field in a query **4 times on a same field** with **different filters**.
something like

```
SELECT Date1,CC,BU, SUM(Amount),SUM(Amount),SUM(Amount),SUM(Amount)
FROM MainTable<br>
GROUP BY CC,BU,Date1
```

Here
 1st `SUM(Amount)` should be calculated when `Mode='011'`  And `Mode='012'` from MainTable
2nd `SUM(Amount)` should be calculated when `Mode like '03_'` And `Mode Like '05_'` from MainTable
3rd `SUM(Amount)` should be calculated when `Mode like '10_'` from MainTable
4th `SUM(Amount)` should be calculated when `(Mode !='011')` and `(Mode !='012')` `(Mode not Like '03_')` and `(Mode not Like '05_')` from MainTable

How to make this happen? I have tried in many ways but couldn't get the result the way I wanted.
Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE`:

```
SELECT Date1,
  CC,
  BU, 
  SUM(case when mode = '011' then Amount end) Mode011,
  SUM(case when mode = '012' then Amount end) Mode012,
  SUM(case when mode = '013' then Amount end) Mode013,
  SUM(case when mode = '014' then Amount end) Mode014
FROM MainTable
GROUP BY CC,BU,Date1;
```

Or you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select date1, CC, BU,
  [011] Mode011, 
  [012] Mode012, 
  [013] Mode013, 
  [014] Mode014
from
(
  select date1, CC, BU, mode, amount
  from maintable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(amount)
  for mode in ([011], [012], [013], [014])
) piv
```

Comment: Can we include 2 filers in case statment with AND operator?
like  (CASE when (mode = '012' And mode='015)' then Amount end)
also I need to use wild cards too. Is it possible?

Comment: @NishantBhuskade Yes you can use more than one filter in the `CASE`, even wilcards